# Location finder response

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps, location

i used this code for find my location(latitude and longitude) but this code sometimes
response quickly (A few seconds) and sometimes it has a delay of More than 10 minutes  .
where is the problem(s)?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10L,
                5.0f, locationListener);
    }

    private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
        TextView myLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        String latLongString = "";
        if (location != null) {
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;

        } else {
            latLongString = "No location found";
        }
        myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" + latLongString);
    }

    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            updateWithNewLocation(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            updateWithNewLocation(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using GPS_PROVIDER for getting the location.

GPS->This provider determines location using satellites. Depending on conditions, this provider may take a while to return a location fix and give the accurate result about 20ft.

Another provider you can use is NETWORK_PROVIDER.
This provider determines location based on availability of cell tower and WiFi access points and give the accurate result about 200ft and also it consume less memory then GPS_PROVIDER.
Use this permission for NETWORK_PROVIDER

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```